# How to use radix tree to find ipv6?

Tags: algorithm

I want to use the base tree to find ipv6, but I do not know where to start. Hope to have a partner can help, thank you!

Comment: Have you tried googling? this is one of the simplest data structures ever. if you still struggle, then you can ask something like "here's what I did but here's something I can't", but plz not before

Comment: Google search has been used, but there is no best answer, so, I hope someone can provide some ideas!

Comment: refer to https://github.com/highfei2011/ip-radix-tree